# How can I fetch all results from a query with a cursor?

Tags: c++, sql, oracle-pro-c

I'm doing some homework where I'm using SQL with ProC/C++ and I'm using a template given by my professor from a previous assignment. The problem is that the function that displays the results of a query only seems to output a single tuple. I want it to output all of the fetched data, but the syntax is a bit foreign to me.

My query:

```
strcat((char *)sqlQueryToRun," select employeeName from Employees");
```

The execute function:

```
void  prepareAndExecuteIt() {

//  Prepare the query

    //sqlQueryToRun.len = strlen((char *) sqlQueryToRun.arr);
    exec sql PREPARE dbVariableToHoldQuery FROM :sqlQueryToRun;

/* The declare statement, below, associates a cursor with a
 * PREPAREd statement.  
 * The cursor name, like the statement
 * name, does not appear in the Declare Section.
 * A single cursor name can not be declared more than once.
*/

    exec sql declare cursorToHoldResultTuples cursor FOR dbVariableToHoldQuery;

    exec sql open cursorToHoldResultTuples  ;

    exec sql FETCH cursorToHoldResultTuples INTO :outputSupplierName;

    printf("\nSupplier name: %s\n", outputSupplierName);
    exec sql close cursorToHoldResultTuples;
}
```

This only outputs a single name when I know there are more in this table. From what I've read there should be some kind of fetchall() method that I can use, but I'm not sure how to apply it with this syntax.

Trying to loop the fetch statement looks like this and gives the following error message:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        exec sql FETCH cursorToHoldResultTuples INTO :outputSupplierName;
        printf("%s\n", outputSupplierName);
    }
```

`make[1]: *** [/home/cs/prof/4620/myMake1.mk:104: pc1] Error 1`

`make: *** [/home/cs/prof/4620/myMake1.mk:110: HW6.o] Error 2`

Comment: Can't you just loop, fetching one result at a time, until the cursor reaches the end of the result set?

Comment: @paddy When I put the fetch statement into a loop it throws errors. Unfortunately the Pro C compiler we're using provides no useful information as to what's going wrong, but I'll try to keep toying with it. However, if I just keep pasting that fetch statement over and over, it keeps giving me tuples. Weird.

Comment: The information you just provided, and the actual error messages being thrown, ought to be included as critical information with your question.  Otherwise it's easy to see this as [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/200806).  I don't know what this "Pro C" thing is you're using, but your question is tagged as C++.  The code shown is not C++.

Comment: Sorry, ProC from what I understand is an SQL programming language from Oracle Databases. The host language is C++ but I think the precompiler is called ProC. I'm not too sure myself but the language I'm writing in is C++. I'll change the title and add the error message to the post.

Comment: Have you searched Stack Overflow for similar questions? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle-pro-c%5D+fetch

Comment: I did, but your link lead me to a thread that I hadn't seen before. Seems that a while loop will work but a for loop does not. Thank you, I think I can figure something out now.